# Java, swing, JFrame and JPanel

Tags: java, swing, menu, panel

I have main window in my program - class that inherit JFrame, this window have JMenuBar.

In code I dynamically create instance of JPanel with some components and set this panel to main window as content pane.

But after this menu bar intersects with my panel, the part of panel is behind menu bar. This continues until I change my window size.

After this intersection disappears, and menu panel placed under menu bar without intersect.

```
JFrame view = ApplicationContext.getInstance().getView();
JPanel panel = new TherapeuticProfile().getRootPanel();
view.setContentPane(panel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this after the window is displayed? In which case you will need `revalidate`.

Doing this off the AWT EDT? In which case you'll need to stop doing that.

(Also statics, as in `ApplicationContext.getInstance()` are a really bad idea in any program.)

Comment: In addition... In my program I'm use MVC pattern and in ApplicationContext that is singleton i'm store only links to Model, View and Controller. Why it's "really bad idea"?